# writing a php function to verify data in an array

Tags: php

How would i go about writing a function that would handle the data in an array?

What i mean is, can i use

```
function CheckStuff($_POST){}
```

instead of

```
function CheckStuff($_POST['var1'], $_POST['var2']){}
```

Reason im asking is i need the function to work through all the values stored in the array and there are quite a few.

Comment: Do you need each parameter to do something different?  Or are they all having the same checks done on them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.

```
function CheckStuff($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [array_filter()](http://php.net/array_filter).  You can define a function, then pass every value of your array through `array_filter()`, and return only the values that you need:

```
function verifyData($item)
{
    //do some stuff
    return ($item_is_good) ? true : false;
}

$goodValues = array_filter($_POST,'verifyData');
```

If you just want to modify each value of $_POST according to some criteria, you could use [array_map()](http://php.net/array_map):

```
function doSomeStuff($item)
{
    $item = $item++;
}

$output = array_map($_POST,'doSomeStuff');
//all of the values in $_POST have now had 1 added to them
```

Answer (score 1):

I use something like the following to loop through an unknown number of array items.

```
while( list( $field, $value ) = each( $_POST )) {
  // do something with each array element value
  myFunction( $value );
}
```

More on the list() function here:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_array_list.asp

More on the each() function here:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_array_each.asp

Comment: Any specific reason why you choose `while (list = each)` over `foreach .. as`?